# UnitOfWork and DbContext: thread safety with DI

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core, thread-safety, unit-of-work

I'm working on a .NET Core 2.2 Console Application that hosts an `IHostedService`:

```
public class MqttClientHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    [...]
    public MqttClientHostedService(
        ILogger<MqttClientHostedService> logger, 
        IOptions<MqttClientConfiguration> mqttConfiguration, 
        IPositionService positionService)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.config = mqttConfiguration;
        this.positionService = positionService;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttClient();
        mqttClient.Connected += async (s, e) => await MqttClient_Connected(s, e);
        mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceived +=
            async (s, e) => await MqttClient_ApplicationMessageReceived(s, e);

        await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(
            new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                .WithTcpServer(config.Value.Host, config.Value.Port).Build());
    }

    private async Task MqttClient_ApplicationMessageReceived(
        object sender, MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
        await positionService.HandleMessage(message);
    }

    [...]
}
```

This `IPositionService` is a manager that inspects the message and checks if it can be saved inside our database:

```
public class PositionService : IPositionService
{
    [...]

    public PositionService(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<PositionService> logger)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task HandleMessage(string message)
    {
        Entity entity = await unitOfWork.EntityRepository.GetByMessage(message);

        [...]

        await unitOfWork.EntityRepository.UpdateAsync(entity);
        await unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    [...]
}
```

`IUnitOfWork` is a wrapper around Entity Framework Core `DbContext` (please don't judge me, I have reasons to do this):

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    [...]

    public UnitOfWork(MyContext myContext)
    {
        this.myContext = myContext;

        EntityRepository = new EFRepository<Entity>(myContext);
    }

    public async Task Save()
    {
        await myContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

`EFRepository<T>`, that implements `IRepository<T>` interface, is a wrapper around `DbSet<T>` (again, please don't judge me). No relevant code here.

Console Application's Program.cs is configured like that:

```
[...]
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
        c => c.UseSqlServer("[...]", options => options.UseNetTopologySuite()),
        ServiceLifetime.Transient);

    services.AddTransient<IPositionService, PositionService>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EFRepository<>));
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

    services.AddHostedService<MqttClientHostedService>();

    [...]
});
```

Problem is that `PositionService.HandleMessage` is being called many times per second, and being that `DbContext` is not thread safe I get this error message:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
>   completed.

I solved this issue by removing `IUnitOfWork` from `PositionService`'s dependencies, injecting instead an `IServiceScopeFactory`, and doing:

```
using (IServiceScope serviceScope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();

    [...]
}
```

This way works, but I don't like it. It seems like a trick, and I don't like the fact that my `PositionService` knows about `Dependency Injection` and has to deal with scopes.

My question is: there's a better way to solve this problem without touching my classes? Should I make the whole `UnitOfWork` thread safe? Or maybe create it by hand without using DI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem is that `MyContext` is held captive as a Captive Dependency in the following object graph:

```
MqttClientHostedService
    -> PositionService
        -> UnitOfWork
            -> MyContext
```

All types in this graph are registered as `Transient`, but still, services that act as *hosted service* (e.g. your `MqttClientHostedService`) are resolved only once for the duration of the application and cached indefinately. This effectively makes them a singleton.

In other words, `MyContext` is accidentally kept alive by the single `MqttClientHostedService` and because multiple messages can come in in parallel, you have yourself a race condition.

The solution is to let each `ApplicationMessageReceived` event run in its own unique little bubble (a scope) and resolve a new `IPositionService` from within that bubble. For instance:

```cs
public class MqttClientHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    [...]
    public MqttClientHostedService(
        ILogger<MqttClientHostedService> logger, 
        IOptions<MqttClientConfiguration> mqttConfiguration, 
        IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.config = mqttConfiguration;
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    [...]
    private async Task MqttClient_ApplicationMessageReceived(
        object sender, MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
        {
            positionService = scope.ServiceProvider
                .GetRequiredService<IPositionService>();
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
            await positionService.HandleMessage(message);
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: In this case, because the hosted service depends on the `IServiceProvider`, it should be part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (your application's entry-point infrastructure). Best is to move all business logic out of this hosted service.